# wpf datagrid cell background color doesnt fill completely

Tags: wpf, datagrid

The background color leaves tiny space between the cell & grid lines. How could I make it fill completely? I have tried tried padding/margin = 0.

Screenshot: [image: http://s21.postimg.org/xqe4mt4dv/Data_Grid_Cell_Background.png]

Any styling experts out there?

```
 <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
     <DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
           <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
        </Style>
     </DataGrid.CellStyle>
  </DataGrid>


  Data = new Dictionary<int,string>();         
     for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        Data.Add(i, "Text");
  DataContext = Data;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one's easy. Set the `BorderThickness` to `0`:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.CellStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Next time you wanna find out why things look how they look, give Snoop a try. Check the controls and panels, and their properties (in this case, it could be either Margin, Padding or BorderThickness), to see what you have to tweak from XAML.

Comment: This will make the selection border disappear, but for the truly obsessive, you can add a `Trigger` to the `Style` for "IsSelected" and reset the border thickness to 1.